# Android Hardware Menu not showing properly

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

Am working on an application that is targeting  `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`  and has a `android:minSdkVersion="8"`, the issue am having is this, am trying to implement the hardware menu and its not showing the familiar 3 menu option below the screen and the images, instead its been displayed straight, how can i make this show properly. and by the way am using the sherlock

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_option_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.about:

            break; 
            case R.id.prayer:

            break;
        case R.id.privacy:

            break;
        case R.id.contact:

            break;
            case R.id.terms:

            break;
        case R.id.exit:

            break; 
        }
        return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running an Emulator? If yes, check this:

[No software buttons for the ICS emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396510/no-software-buttons-for-the-ics-emulator)

If you are not running an emulator, of it this is not your case, you should take a look here instead:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: @ carlos, i am running an Emulator and a device, and it appears the same way, but is there any way, i can still make this show the way i want which is the 3option menu below

Comment: You should activate the buttons on your emulator as it's sayed in my the first link I gave to you. Anyway, the menu button could not show up because of what's said in the second link, since Google decided to remove it and add it to the regular user interface.

Comment: Carlos, thank you for your response so far but is there no way around this, for it to show the way i want,

Comment: True, there is no way to show the menu button since Google removed it in recent versions...I'm sorry for you!

Anyway, you could take my answer as valid, since I gave you a valid response. :)

Comment: Mmm, I think that I've found your solution. Check this: http://techblog.rokoder.com/android-missing-menu-button/

You only have to change the targetSdkVersion to less than 11 (concretely you have this target). Of course, this won't be a valid solution if you are using an API that requires you to have target 11 or higher.

Comment: I think that you missed my last message. Just wanted to be sure that you will read it at some point, it seems to work ok.