# AVD Emulator doesn't show the hardware buttons

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, galaxy

I'm trying to emulate a specific device (Samsung Galaxy S3) but when i start the emulator i haven't the hardware buttons.

Device Setting:

[image: Device Settings]

AVD Setting:

[image: AVD Settings]

I think that the issue is caused by the SKIN WXGA720 but if i change i have a different screen resolution or Software Buttons instead of Hardware.
I don't want to display software buttons but only hardware.

I also need to keep 320dpi as screen density when i check with

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
```

Did anyone found and solved the same issue?

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15100427/3168859)

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11252510/3168859) too..

Comment: Already seen but not solved my issue. In addition I have latest ADT version with different UI.

Comment: please check the `Hardware Keyboard Present checkbox` and see if hardwre buttons are enabled or not...

Comment: Kindly check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8515991/3168859),...please..

Comment: With WXGA800 i got 800x1280 resolution instead of 720x1280. Check my comment in "mike_m" answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see hardware buttons choose this skin in AVD settings `Skin with dynamic hardware controls`

Comment: This solve the Hardware Buttons issue but when i check display density with "getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;" i got 160dpi instead of 320dpi.

Comment: I created device like yours, and `getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi` returns 320 for me, even with `Skin with dynamic hardware controls`

Comment: I solved the wrong density issue just removing <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/> from manifest.xml (used for some tests).